# How to use AND operator in XPath?

Tags: php, xml, xpath

XML is like

```
 <a id="1">
   <b>value1</b>
   <b>value2</b>
 </a>
```

I want to write XPath to find id of `<a>` where there will be two `<b>` child nodes having fix value `value1` and `value2`. I tried to to find out XPath with condition like

```
$xml->xpath('*[b=value1] | *[b=value2]');
```

`value1` and `value2` are present in `<b>` node, but I can not get exactly as I am using XPath first time.

Comment: This is bad idea find element by value, because trivial element finding what get value element...

Comment: @kjhughes sorry but I realy don't undestand why search element by value. In common, element search by id or over will be get value element, sorry for my English. I think reading can't undestand my comment.

Comment: @Naumov: You're right that `@id` based search can be preferable, and in this case it looks possible, but let's give OP the benefit of the doubt that his real case is more complicated, and that this is just a simplified case.  Searching for elements based on their values is not intrinsically a "bad idea".  Thanks.

Comment: @kjhughes Sorry I bad spock in English because, translate Russian to English, and English to Russian and can make error. Sorry again and best regards.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following XPath,

```
//a[b = 'value1' and b = 'value2']/@id
```

will select `id` attributes of all `a` elements with a child `b` element having string value equal to `value1` **AND** another child `b` element having string value equal to `value2` as requested.

Comment: Aaah - that's where I was struggling ... the position of the `@id` in the XPath query. Much neater than my answer (which I'll remove now) ;)

Comment: Thank you. It is working fine. but when there are more elements then it is not working as expected. as  eg.   there are other elements also in <a> tag like <c> </c>

Comment: You're welcome.  You can add `and c = 'value3'` for `c` or you can add `and * = 'value3'` for any child element of `a`.  If this doesn't meet your needs, please ask a new question, making sure to show examples of what should and what should not match.  Thanks.

Answer (score -3):

[`contains`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-contains) function can do it.

```
$nodes = $xpath->query("//b[contains(., 'value1')] | //b[contains(., 'value2')]");
```

And then, to get the parent id

```
$parent_id = $nodes->item(0)->parentNode->getAttribute("id");
```

A demo (with HTML) [here](https://3v4l.org/s8smP).

Comment: This answer is wrong.  It does not capture the requested AND notion, and it uses string containment tests where string equality tests should be used.

Comment: Use of contains() instead of "=" is a common mistake made by people who haven't read the spec.